# Jquery datatable - pagniation DOM

Tags: jquery, datatables

Datatable pagination controls need to be on top of the table and controls should be number of records and pagination buttons and custom action to download the excel sheet.

Based on these controls i have writen the sDOM below..

```
"sPaginationType": "two_button",
 "sDom": '<"top"<"actions">lfpi<"clear">><"clear">rt<"bottom">',
```

I don't want show label with dropdown option 10,15...How to remove the show with drop down and actions are not working good.Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove `l` character (length) and see.

```
"sDom": '<"top"<"actions">fpi<"clear">><"clear">rt<"bottom">',
```

### Detail

```
l - Length changing
f - Filtering input
t - The table!
i - Information
p - Pagination
r - pRocessing
< and > - div elements
<"class" and > - div with a class
Examples: <"wrapper"flipt>, <lf<t>ip>
```